# How to map through component right?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie and I start to learn react js.
So now I have component which has svg icons inside:

```
export default class IconPick extends Component {
    render() {
        const { icon, size = 20, className, ...extraProps } = this.props;
        let path;
        let viewBox;

        switch ( icon ) {
            case 'envelope':
                viewBox = '0 0 512 512';
                path = 'M502.3...';
                break;
            case 'globe':
                viewBox = '0 0 496 512';
                path = 'M336.5...';
                break;
            case 'plus':
                viewBox = '0 0 24 24';
                path = 'M24...';
                break;
        }
        if ( ! viewBox ) {
            return null;
        }
        if ( ! path ) {
            return null;
        }

        const iconClass = [ 'myicon', 'myicon-' + icon, className ].filter( Boolean ).join( ' ' );

        return (
            <SVG
                aria-hidden
                role="img"
                focusable="false"
                className={ iconClass }
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width={ size }
                height={ size }
                viewBox={ viewBox }
                { ...extraProps }
            >
                <Path d={ path } />
            </SVG>
        );
    }
}
```

So everything working fine like that:

```
<IconPick icon={'globe'} />
```

So now I want to display every icon, but I don't know how to map right. I can do something like this, but this is not practical:

```
<div>
    <IconPick icon={'globe'} />
    <IconPick icon={'envelope'} />
    <IconPick icon={'plus'} />
</div>
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX has a slight different syntax. Try this:

```
<div>
    {["globe", "envelope", "plus"].map(icon => (
      <IconPick key={icon} icon={icon} />
    ))}
 </div>
```

More on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can save icon names into array and map over it in render:

```
const icons = ['globe', 'envelope', 'plus'];

//...
return (
  <div>
     {icons.map(icon => <IconPick key={icon} icon={icon} />)}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array icon-name like this: 
`const arrIcon = ["globe", "envelope", "plus"]`

And then, use map operator to render a list Icon:

```
<div>
    {arrIcon.map((icon, index) => (
      <IconPick key={index} icon={icon} />
    ))}
</div>
```